# disable different dropdown base on different id

Tags: jquery

I want to disable or enable 6 dropdown with 6 checkbox . i did this in my way by   6 function but want only 1 function for this . can it be done ?

this is the screenshot of my html and below is my code .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5btU.png)

```
$('#check_policy1').click(function(){
    if($('#check_policy1').is(':checked')){
        $(this).closest('.row').children('div:nth-child(3)').children('div').children('select.a').removeAttr('disabled');              
    }
    else { 
        $(this).closest('.row').children('div:nth-child(3)').children('div').children('select.a').attr('disabled', 'disabled');                                
    }
});    
$('#check_policy2').click(function(){
    if($('#check_policy2').is(':checked')){
         $(this).closest('.row').children('div:nth-child(3)').children('div').children('select.a').removeAttr('disabled');  
     }
     else {
         $(this).closest('.row').children('div:nth-child(3)').children('div').children('select.a').attr('disabled', 'disabled');              
     }
});
```

Comment: please format the posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) can be used. You need to use `this` in the event handler, which refers to element which invoked the event handler.

```
 $('#check_policy1, #check_policy2').change(function() {
     $(this)
         .closest('.row')
         .children('div:nth-child(3)')
         .children('div')
         .children('select.a')
         .prop('disabled', !this.checked);      

 });
```

Alternatively you can assign a common class to all check-boxes and then use Class Selector.

```
 $('.check_policy').change(function() {
     $(this)
         .closest('.row')
         .children('div:nth-child(3)')
         .children('div')
         .children('select.a')
         .prop('disabled', !this.checked);      

 });
```